# Implement spacing between td cell in the table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I created a table which consist of 1 row and it consists of 3 td cell in the table. However, the td cells are somewhat messy as it is close together even though I align the content in the td cell. My code is found below...

```
 <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="color:white;background-color:#000000;">Events Today: <font></font></td>
                    <td align="left" id="totalattack" style="color:white;background-color:#000000;">0      </td>
                    <td align="right"id="todaytime" style="color:white;background-color:#000000;">Current Time</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

    window.onload=startTime;
    function startTime() {
        var today = new Date();
        var h = today.getHours();
        var min = today.getMinutes();
        var s = today.getSeconds();
        var y = today.getFullYear();
        var mon = today.getMonth()+1;
        var d = today.getDate();
        min = checkTime(min);
        s = checkTime(s);
        mon = checkTime(mon);
        d = checkTime(d);
        document.getElementById('todaytime').innerHTML = "   Local Date:"+ d + "/" + mon + "/" +y + "   Local Time:" + h + ":" + min + ":" + s + " SGT ";
        var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
    }
    function checkTime(i) {
        if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
        return i;
    }
```

My image is like this....

[image]

My question is how to create spacing between the 0 and the local date....
I want space between the 0(Events Today) and the local date.. so that it wont be messy.... How to do it? Please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some possibilities to do so. Reynald's, Elvis, JavaEvgen is ok.

Another css-like is

```
#todaytime, #totalattack { padding: 0 10px;}
```

Spaces after tags have usally no effect, multiple space between in counted as one space. Use non-breaking space when you want each space to have an effect ( )

```
document.getElementById('todaytime').innerHTML = "&nbsp;Local Date:" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

try this css

```
table > tr > td{ padding: 0 10px;}
```

add some padding to create space between each column

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this:

```
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0 10px;
}
```

And "play" with `border-spacing` property

Answer (score 0):

Add some padding into css or in your html directly like:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td style="... padding-right: 10px;">...</td>
      <td style="... padding-right: 10px;">...</td>
      <td style="...">...</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Do not add padding to the last column if you do not want white space there.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this:

```
table, th, td  {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for cellpadding & cellspacing

Comment: <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">